# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'

Tags: python

Getting the following error with my code ...

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'

Any idea why? Trying to run a loop where it looks at each student's weighted average score, and then assigns them a letter grade A - F ... For some reason the loop refuses to work when it tries to pull the letter grade.

Using python 3.7.6

```
steve = {"Name": "Steve",
         "Homework": [90, 97, 75, 92],
         "Quizzes": [88, 40, 94],
         "Tests": [75, 90]}
alice = {"Name": "Alice",
         "Homework": [100, 92, 98, 100],
         "Quizzes": [88, 40, 94],
         "Tests": [75, 90]}
tyler = {"Name": "Tyler",
         "Homework": [0, 87, 75, 22],
         "Quizzes": [0, 75, 78],
         "Tests": [100, 100]}
print(steve)
print(alice)
print(tyler)


students = []
students = [steve, alice, tyler]

for i in students:
    print(f"Name: {i['Name']}\nHomework: {i['Homework']}\nQuizzes: {i['Quizzes']}\nTests: {i['Tests']}")


numbers = []
def average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)

def get_weighted_average(student):
        homework_average = average(student["Homework"])
        quiz_average = average(student["Quizzes"])
        test_average = average(student["Tests"])
        weighted_score = homework_average*.1 + quiz_average*.3 + test_average*.6
        return weighted_score

print(f"Steve's: {get_weighted_average(steve)}")
print(f"Tyler's: {get_weighted_average(tyler)}")
print(f"Alice's: {get_weighted_average(alice)}")

def get_letter_grade(score):
if score >= 90:
    return 'A'
elif score >= (80):
    return 'B'
elif score >= (70):
    return 'C'
elif score >= (60):
    return 'D'
else:
    return 'F'

print(get_letter_grade(50))
print(get_letter_grade(100))
print(get_letter_grade(72.5))

for i in students:
    print(f"Name: {i['Name']}'s weighted score is {get_weighted_average(i)}")
    print(f"Name: {i['Name']}'s letter grade is: {get_letter_grade(i)}")
```

Comment: please provide a full traceback.  Not sure where in your code that's triggering that error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fanjin/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 58, in <module>
    print(f"Name: {i['Name']}'s letter grade is: {get_letter_grade(i)}")
  File "/home/fanjin/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 41, in get_letter_grade
    if score >= 90:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'

Comment: in your last line: `get_letter_grade()` takes `score` as an argument and you are passing it a `student`

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's not my question, I just ran the code

Answer (score 3):

At the end instead of `get_letter_grade(i)` you need `get_letter_grade(get_weighted_average(i))`

Comment: Amazing! This was it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the last two lines, where `i` is a dictionary, and was used as an argument for the `get_letter_grade` function, which should accept integers as an argument.

Did you mean `get_letter_grade(get_weighted_average(i))`?

In the future, it would be good practice to check the data type of arguments in functinos so it would be easier for you to see where the error occurs.