# Why am I getting TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125864/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-dict-and-int) post, but unfortunately I'm not able to translate it into a solution for my own case (I am a beginner, 6 weeks into my first Python course).

**Objective**
I have a dictionary with `{'str':int}` pairs.  I am trying to evaluate the `int` values, and for those that are equal to or greater than a specific value, I'd need the corresponding key 'str' appended to a list (which is empty and initialized).

**Attempted Code**

```
scores = {"John": 81, "Doe": 26, "Jane": 80, "Smith": 22, "Bob": 89}
passed = []
for values in scores:
    if scores.values() >= 65:
        passed.append(scores.keys())
print(passed)
```

I'm getting:

```
...in <module>
    if scores.values() >= 65:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

I've tried many differing permutations of the above but I can't seem to figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong.  Appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Please go through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) first before you treat Python code as if it were a natural language.

Comment: If you have `for values in scores:`, then the `values` would be "John", "Doe", "Jane", "Smith", "Bob". It's better to use another name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close with your code. You can't use a >= to compare a dict with an integer. Instead, you need to iterate through the dict and compare each value.

```py
scores = {"John": 81, "Doe": 26, "Jane": 80, "Smith": 22, "Bob": 89}
passed = []
for key, value in scores.items():
    if value >= 65:
        passed.append(key)
print(passed)
```

As mentioned in comments below you can also make a one liner version of this code that does the same thing. As a beginner in python, my version may help you understand what's happening and as you develop your skills you can make your code more compact. Happy coding!

Comment: This is correct, but then the OP would need to understand what `.items()` does and also the concept of tuple unpacking

Comment: Agreed. Luckily, even without a deep understanding of those things this code is still relatively readable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very straightforward task. You can just use a `list` comprehension for this (*one-liner* version) as shown below.

```py
scores = {"John": 81, "Doe": 26, "Jane": 80, "Smith": 22, "Bob": 89}

## here is the list comprehension, check it out o.O
passed = [k for k in scores if scores[k] >= 65]

print(passed)
```

Result:

```
['John', 'Jane', 'Bob']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `dict.items()` to access both the key and value of each mapping.

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) can be used here:

```py
passed = [k for k, v in scores.items() if v >= 65]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `for some_variable in some_dictionary:` for a dictionary, your `some_variable` will hold the individual keys (one key at a time), not the values.

So, since you did `for values in scores:`, then the `values` would be "John", "Doe", "Jane", "Smith", "Bob". So, it's better to use another name, say, `key`.

Also, note that `.values()` will return *an iterator that goes through multiple values*, so you can't compare `scores.values()` directly with `65` (you'll get a **TypeError**).
To get a single value, you can do it with `scores[key]`.

Similarly, `.keys()` will return *an iterator that goes through multiple values*. Since you already have a singular `key`, you can just append the key.

```py
scores = {"John": 81, "Doe": 26, "Jane": 80, "Smith": 22, "Bob": 89}
passed = []
for key in scores:
    if scores[key] >= 65:
        passed.append(key)
print(passed)
```

I hope this is straightforward enough.
There are better ways to loop through a dictionary, though (see other answers).